# Ionicons: How to add custom icons

Tags: ionic-framework, ionicons

I want to add some SVG icons to the default Ionicons set.

I'm following [these steps](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons#build-instructions) to build them from the source without success:

1. Put my svg icon in `src/`: `src/my-icon.svg`
2. Edit my manifest file with a custom prefix `"prefix": "my-",`
3. Run, `python ./builder/generate.py`

`ionicons.svg` appear to be modified but it's not changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended you take a look at [this excellent article by Omar Wazir](http://www.omerwazir.com/custom-icons-with-ionicons), his instructions worked out great for me. In short, he tells you to install all the dependencies, get Ionicons, put your custom icon in the `/src/` folder and to run `python ./builder/generate.py` after which he tells you to move some files to these folders:

```
ionicons\css    ->    <ionicApp>/www/lib/ionic/css/
ionicons\fonts  ->    <ionicApp>/www/lib/ionic/fonts/
ionicons\scss   ->    <ionicApp>/www/lib/ionic/scss/ionicons/
```

Also when you run the `python ./builder/generate.py` command, it should tell you that the script has found a new icon. Perhaps this information can help you solve your problem.

Comment: I've followed these steps but the build process doesn't modify any of the files I should include in my Ionic app. For example, `ionicons.svg` remains the same

Comment: Could you try it with a different icon or change the filename of the icon you are trying to add?

Comment: I've tried: adding a new file, replacing an svg of the set with a custom icon keeping the same filenamem editing a file already in the set overriding the svg path with my icon's path. None worked.
Thanks for your help ;)